# When you publish changes to an Azure Synapse workspace, are currently running pipelines interrupted?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Attempting to understand the limitations of publishing new changes to the workspace.

Specifically, if we publish changes to a pipeline in a workspace, will current runs of that pipeline be interrupted?

And, if we publish changes to a pipeline in a workspace, will all other current runs of other pipelines be interrupted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When your pipeline is triggered/already running it will use the most recent(latest) published code. Updating a pipeline (through UI publish or otherwise) does not interfere with existing pipeline runs.

*And, if we publish changes to a pipeline in a workspace, will all other current runs of other pipelines be interrupted?* - No other pipelines will not be interrupted.